# Problemas con acentos y ñ en php

Tags: php, utf-8

Hola e estado desarrollando un script que genera una imagen a partir de un texto el cual es el siguiente:

```
<?php
 ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$font ='Amperzand.ttf';
$fuente_tamano = 25;
$texto="Es irónico que el amor sea lo más bonito y lo más letal.";

utf8_encode($texto);
$im = imagecreate(400,400);

$fondo=imagecolorallocate ($im, rand(0,255), rand(0,100), rand(0,255));
//Colores
$blanco = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
$gris=imagecolorallocate ($im, 160, 160,160);
$negro=imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 0);
$colorGris = imagecolorallocate($im, 200, 200, 200);
$colorAzul = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);


$lines1 = explode('|', wordwrap(utf8_encode($texto), 28, '|'));

$y=50;

foreach ($lines1 as $line1) {
    {
    $line1=trim($line1);
                    //$line1 = str_pad($line1, 30,"0", STR_PAD_BOTH);
    $marco= ImageTTFBBox ($fuente_tamano, 0, $font, $line1);
    $x = (400 - ($marco[2]-$marco[0])) / 2;
    $y += 30;

    // El texto negro para que lo usaremos como borde
    imagettftext($im, $fuente_tamano, 0, $x + 2 , $y + 1 , $negro, $font, $line1);
    imagettftext($im,$fuente_tamano, 0, $x - 2 , $y - 1 , $negro, $font, $line1);

    // El texto blanco
    imagettftext($im,$fuente_tamano, 0, $x , $y, $blanco, $font, $line1);

    }       
}
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Como pueden apreciar la variable

> $texto

contiene una frase Con acentos que a la hora pasarla a una imagen queda incompleta y con errores.

Me pregunto si existe alguna función que resuelva ese problema y como implementarla en este código .

E probado `utf8_decode();` pero no logro solucinarlo

Usando la solución dada de usar `utf8_encode();` e dejado el escript de esta manera pero igual sigue el problema  espero alguien me pueda decir donde es que falla.

Comment: ¿Intentaste con otra font? La que estás usando no contiene Ñ ni tildes

Comment: si amigo e intentado con otras font y si ellas pero igual da el mismo problema

Comment: ¿El HTML tiene la codificación utf-8 también? Revisa lo dicho en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967), sobre todo los **niveles 1 y 2** para tu caso concreto.

Comment: ya revise la pregunta y ise los cambios necesarios y continua dando el mismo error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes probar colocando esto a tu archivo PHP:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
```

De igual manera debes corregir la siguiente línea:

```
$lines1 = explode('|', wordwrap(utf8_encode($texto), 28, '|'));
```

A:

```
$lines1 = explode('|', wordwrap(utf8_decode($texto), 28, '|'));
```

como te habían mencionado utiliza **utf8_decode**

Saludos

Comment: mira lo que me pusieron antes : no uses utf8_decode(); usa utf8_encode(); ya que lo estas "decodificando" a utf8 y lo que necesitas es "codificarlo". pero tu solución funciono

Comment: para servirte compañero, saludos cordiales

Answer (score 2):

no uses `utf8_decode();` usa `utf8_encode();` ya que lo estas "decodificando" a utf8 y lo que necesitas es "codificarlo".

Comment: podrias agregar documentacion y un ejemplo basico, recuerda que hay otros usuarios que pueden tener el mismo problema

Comment: podrías darme algún ejemplo de como implementarlo en el código

Comment: Ya me disculparan pero soy algo principiante en esto pero el problema qiue nos plantea el autor, lo podemos usar como ejemplo, solo es cambiar el `utf8_decode($variable);` por `utf8_encode($variable);` para que de esta manera hacepta las tildes y demas caracteres, el `utf8_encode();` es como si hiciesemos un `&<letra minuscula-mayuscula>acute;` en un texto de una pagina HTML estática, no sé si con esto ya soluciono esto jejej un saludo

Comment: Gracias por el dato pero el problema aun sigue igual

Answer (score 2):

```
private function properText($str){
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
    $str = preg_replace('[a-zA-Z áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ.]+',htmlentities('${1}'),$str);
    return($str); 
}
```

Espero te pueda servir esta función usando `mb_convert_encoding()`, `preg_replace()` y expresiones regulares (regex).
(Quizá haya un mejor regex pero no sé mucho así que, espero te sirva)

Comment: gracias por el dato me podrias dar alguna idea de donde ubicarlo en el script que tengo

Comment: Puedes colocarlo al final, y donde uses el string en vez de colocar $texto colocas properText($texto);

Comment: lo coloque en esta linea : $lines1 = explode('|', wordwrap(properText($texto), 28, '|'));

Comment: pero da error la imagen contiene errores y no se puede mostrar

Comment: utf8_encode($texto); comenta esa linea

Comment: bueno al parecer funciona es solo que  no muestra la imagen en el navegador

Answer (score 0):

tu error esta en la libreria GD, te lo diria con 99.9% se seguridad.
Esposible que este configurada para ISO u otro encode.
pd: estuve 6 meses peleando con un problema similar