# Como puedo leer la ñ en un php

Tags: php

Estoy creando un fichero php donde obtengo datos de unas tablas pero hay una tabla donde la columna se llama USUARIO_CONTRASEÑA entonces cuando intento recuperar me dice que no existe porque no me reconoce la Ñ, hay alguna forma de que la pueda reconocer.
Lo suyo seria renombrar la columna pero no puedo hacer eso. Ya que esa tabla no depende de mi.

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO USUARIOS ( USUARIO,CONTRASEÑA,ROL ) VALUES (".$row['USUARIO'].",'".$row['CONTRASEÑA']."',".$row['ROL'].")";
```

Y hay me da el error Undefined CONTRASEÑA, y al ver que contiene row se ve como la Ñ no la obtiene bien.

Comment: Responde [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/190887/101499) a tu pregunta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero de todo asegúrate de tener declarado UTF-8 en el HTML

```
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8″ />
```

Después deberás declararlo en tu script php

```
<?php

//estableces UTF-8 como tu codificación
ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");

//esto le dice a PHP que usaremos cadenas UTF-8 hasta el final
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
 
//esto le dice a PHP que generaremos cadenas UTF-8
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
```

Asegurate también, en el caso de que trabajes con una base de datos MySql, que tiene la codificación utf8mb4 para tener soporte completo UTF-8, tanto en la opción character set como en la opción collation.

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo solucione agregando un parámetro mas en mi array de Connection

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"PRUEBAS", "UID"=>"admin", "PWD"=>"admin", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
```