# Problema acentos PHP y HTML

Tags: php, html, acentos

Tengo problemas con los acentos en mi web. Siguiendo [este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190301/problemas-con-acentos-y-%C3%B1-en-php) de este foro, añadí a mi fichero las siguientes líneas:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
utf8_decode($estudiante["id"])
```

Este sería mi fichero:

```
<?php
include_once "conexion.php";
include_once "Estudiante.php";
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$estudiantes = Estudiante::obtener();
?>

    <style>
        h3 {
            font-weight: 10;
        }

        header {
          color: #F57B22;
          padding-top: 1vw;
          padding-bottom: 1vw;
          text-align: center;
        }

        table{
            border-collapse: collapse; 
            margin: 25px 0; 
            font-size: 0.8em; 
            font-family: sans-serif; 
            min-width: 450px; 
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); 
        }
        
        thead tr { 
            background-color: #F57B22; 
            color: #ffffff; 
            height: 3em;
            font-size: 1em; 
            text-align: middle;
            padding: 12px 15px;
            border:2px #F57B22;
        }
        
        td{
            
        }
        
        td { padding: 12px 15px; }
        
        tbody tr { border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; } 
        tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: #f3f3f3; } 
        tbody tr:last-of-type { border-bottom: 2px solid #F57B22; }
    </style>
        
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <header>
            <h1>LISTADO DE ESTUDIANTES</h1>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><b>ID<b></th>
                    <th><b>NOMBRE<b></th>
                    <th><b>GRUPO<b></th>
                    <th><b>NOTA<b></th>
                    <th><b>Editar<b></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($estudiantes as $estudiante) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo utf8_decode($estudiante["id"]) ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo utf8_decode($estudiante["nombre"]) ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo utf8_decode($estudiante["grupo"]) ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo utf8_decode($estudiante["nota"]) ?></td>
                        
                        <td>
                            <a href="editar_estudiante.php?id=<?php echo $estudiante["id"] ?>" class="btn btn-warning">
                                Editar
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
include_once "pie.php";
```

La codificación en MySQL es utf8_unicode_ci.

Añado el fichero conexión.php

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $usuario = "_______";
    $contrasenia = "______";
    $base_de_datos = "____";
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $contrasenia, $base_de_datos);
   
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Falló la conexión a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
?>
```

He añadido al fichero conexión la sentencia:     `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` y ahora en vez de salir ? en caracteres especiales, sale �.

Comment: No dices que editor utilizas, pero al momento de guardarlo, asegúrate de que usa utf-8.

Comment: @track3r el cotejamiento de la BBDD es utf8_unicode_ci. Te referías a eso?

Comment: puedes verifiacar en tu base como se muestran los datos ?

Comment: @rpaillao tienen acentos. De hecho en otro script en el mismo servidor utilizo FPDF para generar un PDF con la misma tabla y funciona bien, este PDF se envía a través de un webservice a una app Android. Yo creo que es algo del HTML o del archivo conexión. Le añado

Comment: no, me refiero al fichero de texto de tu código, según el editor y el sistema que uses, windows o linux, lo guarda en un formato u otro, tienes que asegurarte que es utf-8 al momento de guardarlo, por ejemplo, en notepad++ tienes la opción en Encoding -> convert to utf (without bom), mira este enlace: https://www.hesk.com/knowledgebase/index.php?article=87

Comment: @track3r lo estoy haciendo desde el administrador de archivos del posting

Comment: intenta con mysqli_set_charset($conn,"latin1");

Comment: @rpaillao htmlentities me funciona .. es mala solución?